# Loop array sass and create css

Tags: sass, compass-sass, scss-mixins

I have one function in sass like this

```
$positions: left top bottom right;
$short-paddings: lp tp bp rp;
@each $current-position in $positions {
  $i: index($positions, $current-position);
  @for $x from 1 through 2 {
     @each $current-short in $short-paddings{
      .#{$current-short}-#{$x} {
        padding-#{$current-position}: #{$x}px !important;

      }
    }
  }
}
```

When i do output i got something this

```
.pl-1 {
  padding-left: 1px !important;
}

.pt-1 {
  padding-left: 1px !important;
}

.pb-1 {
  padding-left: 1px !important;
}

.pr-1 {
  padding-left: 1px !important;
}

.pl-2 {
  padding-left: 2px !important;
}

.pt-2 {
  padding-left: 2px !important;
}

.pb-2 {
  padding-left: 2px !important;
}

.pr-2 {
  padding-left: 2px !important;
}

.pl-1 {
  padding-top: 1px !important;
}

.pt-1 {
  padding-top: 1px !important;
}

.pb-1 {
  padding-top: 1px !important;
}

.pr-1 {
  padding-top: 1px !important;
}

.pl-2 {
  padding-top: 2px !important;
}

.pt-2 {
  padding-top: 2px !important;
}

.pb-2 {
  padding-top: 2px !important;
}

.pr-2 {
  padding-top: 2px !important;
}

.pl-1 {
  padding-bottom: 1px !important;
}

.pt-1 {
  padding-bottom: 1px !important;
}

.pb-1 {
  padding-bottom: 1px !important;
}

.pr-1 {
  padding-bottom: 1px !important;
}

.pl-2 {
  padding-bottom: 2px !important;
}

.pt-2 {
  padding-bottom: 2px !important;
}

.pb-2 {
  padding-bottom: 2px !important;
}

.pr-2 {
  padding-bottom: 2px !important;
}

.pl-1 {
  padding-right: 1px !important;
}

.pt-1 {
  padding-right: 1px !important;
}

.pb-1 {
  padding-right: 1px !important;
}

.pr-1 {
  padding-right: 1px !important;
}

.pl-2 {
  padding-right: 2px !important;
}

.pt-2 {
  padding-right: 2px !important;
}

.pb-2 {
  padding-right: 2px !important;
}

.pr-2 {
  padding-right: 2px !important;
}
```

But there some wrong css what i need to output is that i in final css i will have something =this

```
.pl-1 {
  padding-left: 1px !important;
}

.pt-1 {
  padding-top: 1px !important;
}

.pb-1 {
  padding-bottom: 1px !important;
}

.pr-1 {
  padding-right: 1px !important;
}

.pl-2 {
  padding-left: 2px !important;
}

.pt-2 {
  padding-top: 2px !important;
}

.pb-2 {
  padding-bottom: 2px !important;
}

.pr-2 {
  padding-right: 2px !important;
}
```

Any idea where i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first loop `@each $current-position in $positions` is causing your problem. You can remove it and achieve what you want with a map:

```
$short-paddings: (
  top: 'pt',
  left: 'pl',
  bottom: 'pb',
  right: 'pr'
);

@for $i from 1 through 2 {
  @each $position, $prefix in $short-paddings {
    .#{$prefix}-#{$i} {
      padding-#{$position}: #{$i}px !important;
    }
  }
}
```

[SASS Maps documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/maps)